# How can I pull out Variables from XML "Like" string of text and numbers using PHP?

Tags: php, string, parsing, html-parsing

Here's what I have to work with:

```
$sample = '<VAR1>TEXT</VAR1><BR><NUM1>123456789</NUM1><BR><NUM2>9</NUM2><BR><NUM3>99</NUM3>';
```

Here's what I would like to end up with:

```
$VAR1 = 'TEXT';
$NUM1 = 123456789;
$NUM2 = 9;
$NUM3 = 99;
```

Thank you in advance, I'm sure the solution is simple, however everything I've tried hasn't worked thus far.

Comment: PHP's [XML Reader](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php) or [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) will do the job for valid XML. However, the text you've posted is not valid XML. You have no root element and those unterminated `<BR>` elements will give you trouble.

Comment: Yup... you nailed it.  Any suggestions?  I guess I could strip the <BR>'s and add the XML elements.

Comment: I'd fix whatever creates that 'XML'. If that's not possible then add a root element, strip the `<BR>` elements and parse the result. Of course, you could just look at using JSON instead, which is a whole lot easier to work with, but that assumes you have some control over the source of that data.

Answer (score 0):

This is really Really REALLY SLOPPY *(I'll say that right up front)* but it does work...

```
<?PHP

$a = '<VAR1>TEXT</VAR1><BR><NUM1>123456789</NUM1><BR><NUM2>9</NUM2><BR><NUM3>99</NUM3>';

preg_match_all("(\<.+\>(.+)\<\/.+\>)U",$a, $r);    

    // 4 TESTING //

    echo '$r:<pre>';
    print_r($r); 
    echo '</pre><hr>';

    /*
    $r Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => <VAR1>TEXT</VAR1>
                [1] => <BR><NUM1>123456789</NUM1>
                [2] => <BR><NUM2>9</NUM2>
                [3] => <BR><NUM3>99</NUM3>
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => TEXT
                [1] => <NUM1>123456789
                [2] => <NUM2>9
                [3] => <NUM3>99
            )
    )
    */

$demo = array();

$demo = array_combine ( array('VAR1'), sscanf($a, '<VAR1>%[^<]</VAR1>') );

foreach ($r[1] as $key => $value) {

    if (strpos($value, '<NUM1>') !== false) {
        $clean = str_replace("<NUM1>", "", $value);
        $demo['NUM1'] = trim($clean);
    }elseif (strpos($value, '<NUM2>') !== false) {
        $clean = str_replace("<NUM2>", "", $value);
        $demo['NUM2'] = trim($clean);
    }elseif (strpos($value, '<NUM3>') !== false) {
        $clean = str_replace("<NUM3>", "", $value);
        $demo['NUM3'] = trim($clean);
    }else{

    }//end if   

}//end foreach

    // 4 TESTING //

    echo 'DEMO:<pre>';
    print_r($demo); 
    echo '</pre><hr>';

    /*
    $demo Array
    (
        [VAR1] => TEXT
        [NUM1] => 123456789
        [NUM2] => 9
        [NUM3] => 99
    )*/

?>
```